# Easeljs: Getimagedata and put it into a bitmap object

Tags: canvas, bitmap, easeljs

So I'm using Easel.js and just want a fast way to threshold an image, then read it back into the bitmap, so that I rotate it and size it and so on. But the code below is not working. The thresholding part works, and if I put putimagedata, that works. But how to get the thresholded data back into the bitmap object?

Roger

```
var canvas, stage, background, imgData, newBackground

(function initializeCanvas() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
    stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas")

    background = new createjs.Bitmap("background1.jpg");
    background.image.onload = handleBackgroundImage_Loaded
})();

function handleBackgroundImage_Loaded(evt) {
    background.x = 0
    background.y = 0
    stage.addChild(background);
    stage.update()

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, background.image.width, background.image.height);

    background.visible = 0

    for (i = 0; i < imgData.data.length ; i = i + 4) {
        brightnessValue = 0.299 * imgData.data[i] + 0.587 * imgData.data[i + 1] + 0.114 * imgData.data[i + 2]
        if (brightnessValue > 150) {

        } else {
            imgData.data[i + 3] = 0  // if perceptual brightness less than some threshold, then that pixel becomes completely transparent.
        }
    }

    background.image.data = imgData.data
    stage.update()

    //context.putImageData(imgData,0,0);        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach for this is to use an off-screen canvas, and then set that canvas as the source for a Bitmap.

```
// Your code
context.putImageData(imgData,0,0); 
// New bmp
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(canvas);
```

This approach is how filters work in EaselJS. This is a great example of what a filter should be used for, and there is actually a ThresholdFilter already supplied in the [extras folder](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/tree/master/extras/Filters) in GitHub.

Usage:

```
// Rough greyscale filter
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(img);
var filter = new createjs.ThresholdFilter(0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0xFF0000, 0x0000FF);
bmp.filters = [filter];
bmp.cache(0,0,img.width,img.height);
```

Hope that helps!